# Initial migrate in laravel 5 with a reference in the ConfigServerProvider fails

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my ConfigServerProvider.php at boot there is a reference to the configs database table. At initial migrate this database table doesn't exist, so I am getting an error. How can I run the first time 'php artisan migrate', while leaving this boot line intact?

```
public function boot() {
    config([
        'version' => "1.0.2",
        'title' => Config::where('name', 'title')->first()->pluck('value')
    ]);
}
```

I added this around the whole config:

```
    if(Schema::hasTable('configs')) { }
```

And that seems to make all work.

Comment: You're gonna need to write some code to check if the table exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app i made this:

```
try {
    $configs = Config::all();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $configs = [];
}
```